# Implementing if else condition inside a mat-cell of a mat-table - Angular 5

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular5, mat-table

I am trying to implement an if else condition inside a mat-cell of a mat-table in my angular application. But I am getting error from the console "ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[NgIf -> TemplateRef]: "

my code is

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="role">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Role</mat-header-cell>        
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user" ngIf="{{user.roles.length == 1}}">
        Admin          
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have `ngIf`, but it should be prefixed with an asterisks: `*ngIf`

Also, with a bound directive attribute like `*ngIf` you don't need to use the curly braces inside of that.  Just doing `*ngIf="user.roles.length == 1"` should be fine.

However, usually you can't have two directives on the same element with asterisks, so using another `<ng-container>` is probably the way to fix this:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="role">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Role</mat-header-cell>
  <ng-container *ngIf="user.roles.length == 1">
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user" >
      Admin          
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Thanks but this will not work since "user" is undefined there in ng-container

Comment: ah yes, perhaps just switch the order of those 2 elements then.  You will have to use 2 elements no matter what since you have two directives that use `*`, and you can only have one per element.

Answer (score 3):

Adding a wrapper `ng-container` did the trick getting the `user` object on parent container and using that paren accessed variable in child container for `*ngIf`.

```html
    <ng-container matColumnDef="role">
      <th *matHeaderCellDef mat-header-cell>Role</th>
      <td *matCellDef="let user" mat-cell>
        <ng-container *ngIf="user.roles.length == 1;else conditionNotMet">
          Admin (Condition is met)
        </ng-container>
      </td>

      <ng-template #conditionNotMet>
        What ever logic...
      </ng-template>
    </ng-container>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have faced for a same kind of issue.. And i came up with following solutions.

1. You can use `[ngClass]` as follows.

> ```
>   <tr mat-footer-row [ngClass]="dataSource.length==0 ? 'hide' : ''" *matFooterRowDef="displayedColumns1"></tr>
> ```

2. Or If you want to hide some cells you can use `[hidden]` attribute. It's like CSS "display: none" property.

> ```
>   <tr mat-footer-row [hidden]="dataSource.length==0" *matFooterRowDef="displayedColumns1"></tr>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a class to set the display as none and will make the trick

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="role">
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Role</mat-header-cell>        
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let user" [ngClass]="'hide':user.roles.length == 1">
    Admin          
</mat-cell>
```

And in your stylesheet file

```
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```